# memset bytewise instead of integer ( 4 bytes )

Tags: c, memset

I am struggling to find the answer to this:

```
#define BUFLEN 8
unsigned short randombuffer[BUFLEN];    
memset(randombuffer, 200 , BUFLEN );
printf("%u", randombuffer[0]);
```

I am getting the answer as 51400 although I was expecting 200.
After debugging I found out that the `randombuffer` is filled with 0xC8 for the first 8 entries. Hence 0xC8C8 is 51400. I was however expecting 0x00C8 for each index in the array.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: C11 draft standard, `7.24.6.1 The memset function Section 2 The memset function copies the value of c (converted to an unsigned char) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by s.`.

Comment: why are you guys giving me negative votes? Just because I did not understand the specs or I dared to ask a question after lots of debugging???

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if I did (and I might), it wouldn't be for not *understanding* the spec. I doubt you *read* it in the first place.

Comment: @infoclogged I don't know where the negative votes are coming from - I think it's silly of whomever is doing it. Anyway, `memset` wouldn't work, a loop is probably your best bet: `for (int i = 0 ; i != BUFLEN ; randombuffer[i++] = 200);` (note the semicolon at the end, because the loop does not have a body).

Comment: Thank you.. I got it now.. I was treating memset as  C/C++ pointer and hence missed the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memset` fills bytes, but it looks like you want to fill words. I don't know if there's a `memset`-like function built in for this, so you might have to do repeated `memset`/`memcpy` instead. Note that if you feel comfortable writing inline assembler you could probably do this pretty efficiently yourself in machine code - although a tight loop using pointers in C is probably close to as fast.

Comment: Well, randombuffer is a word. So randombuffer + 1  should actually be point  to the next word and not the next byte. I think memset internally increments the pointer to point to the next location of filling..right?

Comment: @infoclogged You're assuming an implementation of `memset` that relies on C/C++-style pointer semantics. I think that's where you're going wrong. As other answers point out, as per the spec, `memset` copies bytes, not words, not double words. You can pass whatever pointer you like but it's treating it as bytes. If you were to implement `memset` as you imagine it's implemented, the code would most likely work.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is not reading the spec of memset. memset sets each *byte* to the specified value. Your buffer has most likely 8 entries of two bytes each. Since you passed 8 to memset, both bytes of the first four entries are changed, the rest isn't touched. That's who memset works.

Answer (score -4):

The size calculation in the memset call is not correct. It should be:

```
memset(randombuffer, 200 , BUFLEN * sizeof(*randombuffer) );
```

because individual elements in randombuffer are two bytes in your case and the third parameter in memset takes the amount of bytes of the object, so you have to pass the number of the elements in the object times their size in bytes.

The values in the elements will still remain 0xC8C8, because memset set a value per byte not per element.

To print them out correctly, use the correct specifier for `short`:

```
printf("%hu", randombuffer[0]);
```

or

```
printf("%hx", randombuffer[0]);
```

Comment: Too bad a correct answer got downvoted for no reason.

Comment: Well, this won't give the `0x00C8` value OP apparently wants.

Comment: @Useless Strawman argument. OP wants explanation of behavior, which I have given.

Comment: @Useless Nice counterargument. /s